# Make an endless jQuery short and easy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion on my WordPress website.

Usually it works fine, adding and removing classes when clicking the different tabs, but there is an issue with one of the accordions on the website: When clicking on one of the tabs - it doesn't close the rest of the opened tabs. So I added this code in and it works fine:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#top11").click(function() {
    $("#collapse202").removeClass("in");
    $("#collapse203").removeClass("in");
  });
  $("#top12").click(function() {
    $("#collapse201").removeClass("in");
    $("#collapse203").removeClass("in");
  });
  $("#top13").click(function() {
    $("#collapse201").removeClass("in");
    $("#collapse202").removeClass("in");
  });

});
```

I am sure that there is a way to make it shorter, could some one please explain how to do it more compact?

Comment: And we should guess how the problematic accordion looks like?

Comment: give them all a shared class, then close all the tabs with that class. Then open the specific tab using its id.

Comment: No need to give them all a special class, just selecting all siblings with jQuery and closing them would suffice. Saying that, you need to share your HTML as @Shomz noted.

Comment: How does the html look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML look like that, you can use the `next()` function to target the next sibling element:

```js
$("#top11, #top12, #top13").click(function() {
 $("#top11, #top12, #top13").next().removeClass("in");
 $(this).next().addClass("in");
});
```

```css
.in {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top11">top11</div>
<div id="collapse201" class="in">collapse201</div>
<div id="top12">top12</div>
<div id="collapse202" class="in">collapse202</div>
<div id="top13">top13</div>
<div id="collapse203" class="in">collapse203</div>
```

Comment: What if there are 50 tabs? Will you just list all of them, one by one? All the way `$("#top01, #top02, #top03,#top04,............., top50").click( function($("#top01, #top02, #top03,#top04,............., top50") ` ?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to add `data-id` to each collapsed element. For example:

```
<div id="collapse201" data-id="top11"></div>
<div id="collapse202" data-id="top12"></div>
<div id="collapse203" data-id="top13"></div>
```

And of course you should use a class in your tabs just in case there are lots of tabs in your accordion:

```
<div id="top11" class="clickingTab"></div>
<div id="top12" class="clickingTab"></div>
<div id="top12" class="clickingTab"></div>
```

The JS code could look like this then:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickingTab").click(function() {
    var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
    $("element:not([data-id="+clickedId+"])").removeClass("in");
  });
});
```

There of course could be more efficient ways to solve your problem. But for this particular question this could be the particular solution.

Comment: Same comment as above. What if there are 50 tabs? Will you list each one of them, one by one, all 50 of them?

Comment: @JeremyThille polemics. First of all, you must be out of your sane mind to make a 50 tab accordion. User friendly design? Never heard of it. Second, as I noted, there might be a better solution. Of course I'd use a class instead of 50 ids But since the author never provided the HTML code...

Comment: @JeremyThille forgot to say that nevertheless you do have a point and I edited my answer regarding your comment

Comment: Of course you will never make a 50 tab accordion. It was completely about programming logic. Using a class is infinitely better than listing Ids, your edit is right. And this post is about code improvement so... deserved an upvote :)